# Python: how to remove only first word from a string

Tags: python-2.7

The input string is given below:

```
line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"
```

Output should be "Jumped the Bridge".

I tried

```
s2 = re.match('\W+.*', line).group()
```

But it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex.py", line 7, in <module>
    s2 = re.match('\W+.*', line).group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

So apparently the match failed.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Joe

Comment: instead of re.match re.search does what I needed. That is to strip the first word of a line. In case you are curious why do I need to do such things. This is in the context of using cmd module and trying to collect arguments from a line of command. Thanks to all those who replied.

Answer (score 20):

Python's [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has an optional second parameter called `maxsplit`, to specify the largest amount of splits:

```
line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"
s2 = line.split(' ', 1)[1]
```

To quote the docs for `str.split`:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done

So to explain this code:
`str.split(' ', 1)` creates a list with two elements: the first element being the first word (until it reaches a space), and the second being the rest of the string. To only extract the rest of the string, we use `[1]` to indicate the second element.

Note: If you are concerned about having multiple spaces, use `None` as the first parameter for `str.split`, as follows:

```
line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"
s2 = line.split(None, 1)[1]
```

Comment: Plus 1 because I was unaware of the optional second parameter.

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't tied to regular expression, you could do something like this:

```
In [1]: line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"

In [2]: s2 = ' '.join(line.split()[1:])

In [3]: s2
Out[3]: 'Jumped the Bridge'
```

`line.split()` takes the string and splits it on whitespace, returning a list that contains each word as an items:

```
In [4]: line.split()
Out[4]: ['Cat', 'Jumped', 'the', 'Bridge']
```

From that list, we take the second element (skipping the first word) and everything after it by using `[1:]`:

```
In [5]: line.split()[1:]
Out[5]: ['Jumped', 'the', 'Bridge']
```

And then last piece is joining it all together using `join`, where here we use the space character to 'join' all of the strings in our list back into a single string:

```
In [6]: ' '.join(line.split()[1:])
Out[6]: 'Jumped the Bridge'
```

Comment: Waay complex. Use parameters for split!

Comment: @Moshe Totally forgot about that - +1 to you sir :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `.partition()`:

```
>>> line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"
>>> word, space, rest = line.partition(' ')
>>> word
'Cat'
>>> space
' '
>>> rest
'Jumped the Bridge'
```

To fix what you have now, add a capturing group and use `\w` instead of `\W` (they're opposites):

```
>>> re.match(r'(\w+)', line).group()
'Cat'
```

Comment: Blender, thanks for your answer. Apparently I had been looking at the code for too long today. Because I should have tried s2 = re.search('\W+.*', line).group(). And this would have given me what I wanted. But I had a re.match instead. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Can be simpler:

```
line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"
s2 = " ".join(line.split()[1:])
```

Using regex:

```
line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"
s2 = re.sub('^\S+\s+', '', line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or.........

```
words = ["Cat", "Cool", "Foo", "Mate"]
sentence = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"

for word in words:
    if word in sentence:
        sentence = sentence.replace(word, "", 1)
        break
```

Otherwise....

```
sentence = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"

sentence = sentence.split(" ")
sentence.pop(0)
sentence = " ".join(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete_first_word(p):
    letter = 0
    for e in p:
        if e[0] == " ":
            return line[letter + 1:]
        else:
            letter = letter + 1
line = "Cat Jumped the Bridge"
print delete_first_word(line)
```